# Makefile Explanation

Tags: c, sed, makefile, gnu-make

I am new to makefiles and trying to understand some code:

```
%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $^ -c -Wall
    $(CC) -MM $*.c > $*.dep
    $(OBJECTDUMP) -d -M intel -S $@
    @mv -f $*.dep $*.dep.tmp
    @sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.dep.tmp > $*.dep
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.dep.tmp | fmt -1 | \
      sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.dep
    @rm -f $*.dep.tmp
```

Can someone please explain what the last 5 lines of code are doing?

Comment: they are reformatting the dependency output issue by `gcc -MM` call. For what? dunno...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of those lines is to deal with a problem with dependency handling.

Suppose you have a header file `bar.h`, and a source file `foo.c` that contains the line

```
#include "bar.h"
```

Now generate the dependency file:

```
$(CC) -MM $*.c > $*.dep
```

The file `foo.dep` now contains:

```
foo.o: foo.cc bar.h
```

Wonderful. I'm sure the makefile has a line like `-include *.dep`, so now Make will handle foo's dependencies correctly. But now suppose you edit `foo.c`, remove that `#include` line, and delete the no-longer-needed `bar.h`. The next time you try to `make foo`, Make will read the old `foo.dep` which calls for `bar.h`, see that there is no such header and no known way to build it, and abort. Make will not know that the header is not needed until it rebuilds the dep file, which it cannot do because the header is missing and Make thinks it is needed.

One solution is to delete `foo.dep` when this situation arises (before Make aborts, if possible). Another is to add a line to `foo.dep`:

```
bar.h:
```

which will assuage Make's fears about the missing header. The first approach requires human attention, the second can be automated:

```
@mv -f $*.dep $*.dep.tmp # rename foo.dep -> foo.dep.tmp
@sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.dep.tmp > $*.dep # this does nothing and appears to be vestigal
@sed -e 's/.*://' \ # remove the target, leaving foo.c bar.h
  -e 's/\\$$//' \  # remove line continuation marks, if any
  < $*.dep.tmp | fmt -1 | \ # put each word on its own line
  sed -e 's/^ *//' \ # remove leading whitespace
  -e 's/$$/:/' \ # add a colon to the end of each line (making it a rule)
  >> $*.dep # save the result as foo.dep
@rm -f $*.dep.tmp  # delete the temporary file
```

Comment: The GCC option `-MP` also address this issue without the need for `sed` jiggery-pokery.

Comment: @user657267: Very true. The jiggery-pokery predates that option, which was implemented to make it unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`$*` corresponds roughly to the `%` in the first line.

- The `@mv` line moves the old `basename.dep` file to `basename.dep.tmp`
- The first `@sed` line edits what's in the `basename.dep.tmp`, replacing anything up to a colon with `basename.o:` (because the `$*` is expanded by `make`, not the shell).
- The second `@sed` line and the following line do some more editing — appending another variant of the `basename.dep.tmp` file to the end of `basename.dep`.
- The `@rm` line removes the temporary `basename.dep.tmp` file.

A more thorough analysis of the second `sed` sequence requires more detailed knowledge of what's in the `.dep` file and exactly what `fmt -1` does for you.

However, it seems that the goal is to update the dependencies that apply to the source file, based on the information from the compiler plus massaging it in a way to suit the programmer.  The why is not clear to me.